# Multiple Select Sending Empty String to Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, selection, form-for

I have a `tradie` model that has many `tradie_category` models. In the form for the tradie I added the following:

```
= form_for @tradie do |tradie|
  = tradie.select :tradie_category_ids, @categories, {}, { multiple: true }
```

In the HTML, the following is generated...

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/add_a_tradies/create" class="new_tradie" method="post">
  <input name="tradie[tradie_category_ids][]" type="hidden" value="">
  <select class="form-control" id="tradie_tradie_category_ids" multiple="multiple" name="tradie[tradie_category_ids][]">
    <option value="2">mechanic</option>
    <option value="1">plumber</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I removed the authenticity token and submit button because it's not necessary with my problem. Whenever I do post the form, the params `tradie_category_ids` is returned as an empty string. What's wrong and how do I fix it so I can created multiple tradie categories for the tradie that is created.?

Comment: In your controller, can you do a `puts params.inspect` and show us what the results are? (of course make sure you select something in the tradie category ids) :)

Comment: Yeah I did that already: `:tradie_category_ids => ""`

Comment: `<input name="tradie[tradie_category_ids][]" type="hidden" value="">` where is this hidden field coming from? Could it be overriding you selection?

Comment: @jason328 - but we want to see the rest of it... :)

Comment: @tihom I'm not sure where it's coming from. Rails itself is creating it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems this issue was also reported in another question: [Why is the first element always blank in my Rails multi-select, using an embedded array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929230/why-is-the-first-element-always-blank-in-my-rails-multi-select-using-an-embedde)

They outline the specification for it and how it will be resolved in Rails 4.  The second most popular response says how to apply a fix for it in the mean time.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
= form_for @tradie do |tradie|
  = tradie.select :tradie_category_ids, @categories, {}, { multiple: "true" or 'true' }
```

Note the quotes around

```
{ multiple:  "true" or 'true'  } in
```

Comment: Did this work? on which version of rails you tried this?

Comment: @Swapnil, I think it was last year, I guess Rails 3.2

Comment: I tried this code with rails 3.2.11 but its not working for me.