# Why is there an empty array element in my person_ids hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app I have this model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :person_ids

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :people_projects
  has_many :people, :through => :people_projects

end
```

What I don't understand is:

When I create a new project why is there always one empty element at the beginning of my `person_ids` array:

```
Parameters: {"utf8" => "✓", "project" => {"name" => "Testproject", "person_ids" => ["", "1", "2", "3"]}, "commit" => "Create", "id"=>"77"}
```

This happens not only in my `Project` class but in all other classes with `has_many through` as well and it is causing me a lot of (mostly validation related) trouble.

This is my form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label "People" %>
  <%= f.select(:person_ids, current_user.people.map { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, {:multiple => true}) %>
</div>
```

Thanks to anybody who can shed some light on this.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're creating this, but it looks like it could be from [`:include_blank => true`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) which inserts an empty item at the beginning of arrays.

Comment: That's what I thought too. But there's no blank option in my select box. I posted my form above.

Comment: see no one's answered this...what happens if you *do* put `include_blank => true`?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @dax: I get another option in my select box then: `<option value></option>`

Comment: @MichaelStalker: 3.2.13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe I've found the issue.  It looks like it comes from `{:multiple => true}` as pointed out by [Mike A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573505/mike-a) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933085/2128691) answer:

From the [`select` docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select):

> ## Gotcha
>
> The HTML specification says when multiple parameter passed to select and all options got deselected web browsers do not send any value to server. Unfortunately this introduces a gotcha: if an User model has many roles and have role_ids accessor, and in the form that edits roles of the user the user deselects all roles from role_ids multiple select box, no role_ids parameter is sent. So, any mass-assignment idiom like
>
> `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])`
>
> wouldn’t update roles.
>
> To prevent this the helper generates an auxiliary hidden field before every multiple select. The hidden field has the same name as multiple select and blank value.
>
> This way, the client either sends only the hidden field (representing the deselected multiple select box), or both fields. Since the HTML specification says key/value pairs have to be sent in the same order they appear in the form, and parameters extraction gets the last occurrence of any repeated key in the query string, that works for ordinary forms.

So this is a planned feature that makes sense, however it can have a dark side (as in your case) - evidently this is being changed in Rails 4, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8939205/2128691) from the same linked question.

> You will be able to pass `:include_hidden` option. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5414/files

The same post offers this solution, which deletes all blank values at the model level:

```
before_validation do |model|
  model.subset_array.reject!(&:blank?) if model.subset_array
end
```

Comment: Ah excellent, I think this is the solution. Thanks a lot for researching this. I wasn't able to find it myself, even though I tried really hard. Luckily I found my own solution to this by simply deleting the first element from the array: `person_ids.delete_at(0)`. This works for the moment but it feels a bit like a dirty hack to me. Hopefully I'll be able to upgrade to Rails 4 next year.

Comment: I'm not sure that `delete_at` isn't a better solution as it's a bit more targeted.  glad it helped though!