# Relation has_and_belongs_to_many doesn't save data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've migration tags_words

```
class CreateTagsWords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags_words, id: false do |t|
       t.references :tag
       t.references :word
     end
     add_index :tags_words, :tag_id
     add_index :tags_words, :word_id
  end
end
```

model words and tags:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :namelanguage1, :namelanguage2, :tags_attributes

    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

    def self.search(search)
        if search
            find(:all, :conditions => ['namelanguage1 LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
        else
            find(:all)
        end
    end
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :language_user_id

    has_and_belongs_to_many :words

    def self.search(search)
        if search
            find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
        else
            find(:all)
        end
    end
end
```

and when I'll add tags to words and then save it doesn't save in db (when I write in rails console `Words.find(1).tags` i get empty array.

Comment: How are you trying to save them? (What are the return values when calling save?)

Comment: You'd need to do `Word.find(1).tags` in your console

Comment: Do you have access to your database (with something like PHPMyAdmin)?

Comment: Sorry my mistake: I write Word.fond(1).tags. I save word by controller.

Comment: I make it in localhost by using sqlite3 so i have access only by rails console

Comment: Hmm okay. Would be beneficial to see contents of `tags_words` datatable -- any way you could dump it or something with SQLite3?

Comment: Share the controller code where you are saving the tags.

Comment: hiere you have all tag_controller [link](http://pastebin.com/fmTFsiPN)

Comment: How are the routes defined in routes.rb? Could you share.

Comment: [routes.rb](http://pastebin.com/EaXJsM2J)

Comment: Where exactly do you want to create a tag. Is there some link on words index page that takes you to add a new tag?

Comment: I create tag in [view](http://pastebin.com/Jagi2YU1) and i'll add later this tag to word in [word view](http://pastebin.com/WtYZ6GUb)

Comment: all code are in [github](https://github.com/henio180/stackrails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to use the [<<](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) ActiveRecord method to add to the respective collections you have:

```
#app/controllers/words_controller.rb
def add_tag
    word = Word.find(params[:id])
    tag = Tag.find(params[:id])

    word.tags << tag
end
```

Your problem will either be caused by you not saving your data correctly, or not calling it properly

---

**Update**

If you want to add tags to the `word`'s `tags` collection after you've created a new `word`, you'll be able to do something like this:

```
#app/controllers/words_controller.rb
def create
    @word = Word.new(word_params)
    @word.save
end

private

def word_params
    params.require(:word).permit(:namelanguage1, :namelanguage2, tag_ids: [])
end

#app/models/word.rb
Class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :tag_ids
    after_create :add_tags

    def add_tags
       if tag_ids
           tag = Tag.find(tag_ids)
           tags << tag
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: I just started reading the question and you posted the answer. :/

Comment: It's not the answer - it's just a recommendation. The OP should post updates about how they're modifying the collections. You should still provide input - it will help them out

Comment: I've added this method but i dont'n know how to call it??

Comment: BTW you can try is in the console - just do this:

`word = Word.find(1)`
`tag = Tag.find(1)`
`word << tag` 
`word.tags`

Comment: Thanks - where would you like to add new tags to a word? (which method)?

Comment: when i create new word

Comment: Okay, and which tags would you like to add to the collection?

Comment: Okay thanks, you'd normally use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with this, but can only be used with `has_many :through`. Otherwise, we'd need to call the after_create method & use some virtual params

Comment: could you explain me how I can fix it?? I started my adventure with rails

Comment: Updated for you - you'll have to use `after_create` with virtual attributes. Because you're using Rails 3, I think my code will need tweaking, but it should be okay

Comment: You've got to provide some more info man - can you use the Rails logger or something/

Comment: Unpermitted parameters: tag_ids
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "words" ("created_at", "namelanguage1", "namelanguage2", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 22 Mar 2014 12:33:43 UTC +00:00], ["namelanguage1", "fhjikhki"], ["namelanguage2", "hkhgjk"], ["updated_at", Sat, 22 Mar 2014 12:33:43 UTC +00:00]]

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.0.3

Comment: Good - let me update my answer. BTW your use of `attr_accessible` is only valid for Rails 3

Comment: but when i delete it i can't add anything to db

Comment: Because you need to use Strong Params to create the correct item :)

Comment: "Missing template words/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/henio/Desktop/wordsy/app/views""

Comment: You'll need to create the `/views/words/create.html.erb` file ;)

Comment: Error /logs? You need to be more specific! It's a logical process - if it doesn't work, there'll be a problem somewhere :) I can only use what you provide so you need to provide more details

Comment: WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Word: tag_ids
 app/controllers/words_controller.rb:30:in `create'

Comment: hmmm okay thanks for this. This issue will either be caused by the `protected_attributes` gem, or because `tag_ids` is used by another process. Do you have the `protected_attributes` gem in your GemFile?

Comment: Yes i have gem 'protected_attributes'

Comment: Do you need it for anything else?

Comment: I have user authentication and i use it with gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt" - i think that

Comment: Homebrewed authentication? Are you following the Hartl tutorial? Protected Attributes is depreciated in Rails 4, but can work around it if you need

Comment: I make authentication with this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) but if i can make it easier i'll if you say me how

Comment: OK i changed this and now I have "Couldn't find all Tags with IDs (, 10) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)"

Comment: You'd be much better using [Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)! You'll have to replace your homebrewed  authentication though :(

Comment: Nice, this is very very very good news - it means our callback is working. How are you selecting the IDs? One of them is not being sent

Comment: Words view: <p>
    <%= f.label :tags %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :tag_ids, @all_tags, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true } %>
  </p>

Comment: can you try removing `:multiple` for now? This will send a single ID, which will hopefully send the correct data

Comment: I get now: "Unpermitted parameters: tag_ids"

Comment: Wow okay... did you change any other code? It passed the correct params last time

Comment: CAn you show which params it's sending in the logs? -> `params{}`

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"74Mhbpn9FF/tY/cgfuVmX7ribN4rOkkdUjSgbLNsces=", "word"=>{"namelanguage1"=>"dfdd", "namelanguage2"=>"ddd", "tag_ids"=>"10"}, "button"=>""}

Comment: And your strong params code is the same? You've not changed it? Where does the unpermitted params error happen - controller or model?

Comment: Now i change:  def word_params
      params.require(:word).permit(:namelanguage1, :namelanguage2, :tag_ids)
    end
Ant it's work :D But how can I use multiple?

Comment: For multiple, you'll have to change strong_params back to accepting array, and it will be to work with the `multiple` select element - what were you doing before to return a blank ID?

Comment: OK i changed to params.require(:word).permit(:namelanguage1, :namelanguage2, tag_ids: []) and I get the same problem: Couldn't find all Tags with IDs (, 10, 11) (found 2 results, but was looking for 3)

Comment: Okay, we are making progress. What are you doing to make the first element null in your selector? Are you doing anything strange?

Comment: Now i see in logs: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"74Mhbpn9FF/tY/cgfuVmX7ribN4rOkkdUjSgbLNsces=", "word"=>{"namelanguage1"=>"dfgd", "namelanguage2"=>"dddd", "tag_ids"=>["", "10", "11"]}, "button"=>""}

Comment: No I do nothing with empty element

Comment: Yes - this is fine. The problem is `[""` -- if we can make it so your HTML does not send blank element, the thing should work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929230/why-is-the-first-element-always-blank-in-my-rails-multi-select-using-an-embedde it's a common problem

Comment: OK i write it in this way: tag = Tag.find(tag_ids.to_a.drop(1)) an it's work :D thank you very very very very much for your help.

Comment: Np! You should accept my answer & upvote if it works ;)

Comment: I've accepted your answer but i can't vote up because i don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Lol one of the ironies of SO! I thank you for upvote & hope you continue to make great apps in Rails :)

Comment: Thank you - I just started Rails and I like it ;)

Comment: +1 for the dedication and the solution of course. :)