# Rails 4 - Single Attribute to Accept Array of Values

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, multiple-select

I am needing to have an attribute in my form (:supported_media_types) accept an array of values.

For example, I want the user to be able to click on both JPG and PNG if required.

I have setup a select2 drop down with multiple: true

Is there an easy way to achieve this or am I required to create a join table?

```
<%= f.select :supported_ad_types, supported_types_of_media, {include_blank: true}, {class: 'filter_select', name: 's2id_location_supported_ad_types[]', style:'width:100%;', placeholder: 'Supported File Types', required: true, multiple: true} %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a serialized attribute like this:

1 - Add a column to your migration normally, as text:

```
rails g model Image types:text
rake db:migrate
```

2 - In your class:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :types, Array
end
```

Now, you can do things like:

```
i = Image.new
i.types << "png"
i.types << "jpg"
i.save
=> #<Image id: 1, types: ["png", "jpg"], created_at: "2014-08-11 22:44:08", updated_at: "2014-08-11 22:44:08">
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be passing in a blank value on first record. I changed my (include_blank: false)

Comment: "supported_ad_types"=>["", "JPG", "BMP"],

Comment: That's something to do with the select.

Comment: As for the blank value being persisted, take a look at this (there is also a workaround): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929230/why-is-the-first-element-always-blank-in-my-rails-multi-select-using-an-embedde . And consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: Accepted answer along with Jan.

Comment: Is there a way to now be able to display this data? On my 'show' view, all I see are brackets []. But I am able to see in my logs that the data array is saving

Comment: What do you mean? To just exhibit like: PNG, BMP ?

Comment: What I realized looking at the logs was that the data was being 'submitted' correctly, but not saving. Inside my console I can see: supported_ad_types: [], Trying to figure out why the data is not passing through. I am using Rails 4

Answer (score 2):

use `select_tag 'supported_ad_types[]' ...` to get array params.

In your model use `serializer :supported_ad_types, array` to save array params.