# Creating associated object from collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

I have multiple `Lessons` and most of them have some prerequisites which are themselves other lessons. The `Prerequisite` model represents the relationship and each has a `lesson_id` and `prerequisite_lesson_id`.

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :prerequisites
  has_many :prerequisite_lessons, :through => :prerequisites
end

class Prerequisite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lesson
  belongs_to :prerequisite_lesson, :class_name => "Lesson"
end
```

I'm trying to figure out a way so that:

- When I create a new `Lesson` and select one or more prerequisites from a `collection_select`
- multiple `Prerequisite` objects are created based on what was selected, with the `lesson_id` being the created `Lesson` id.

Here is part of my Lesson controller:

```
def create
  @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)

  if @lesson.save
    if @lesson.prerequisite_ids.length > 0
      @lesson.prerequisite_ids.each do |p|
        Prerequisite.new(lesson_id: @lesson.id, prerequisite_lesson_id: p)
      end
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Lesson created..."
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :new
  end
end

...

def lesson_params
  params.require(:lesson).permit(
    :name,
    :high_tempo,
    :low_tempo,
    :interval,
    :advance_tempo,
    prerequisites_attributes: [
      :lesson_id,
      :prerequisite_lesson_id
    ]
  )
end
```

and my form:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:prerequisite_ids, Lesson.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

UPDATE:

In the logs, I see:

> "lesson"=>{"name"=>"Lesson 6", "high_tempo"=>"200",
>   "low_tempo"=>"100", "interval"=>"10", "advance_tempo"=>"140",
>   "prerequisite_ids"=>["", "3", "4"]}, "commit"=>"Save"} Unpermitted
>   parameter: prerequisite_ids'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a couple of problems here:

One is that you are using `Prerequisite.new(...)` when I think you want to be using `Prerequisite.create(...)`

So your create action should be:

```
def create
  @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)

  if @lesson.save
    if @lesson.prerequisite_ids.length > 0
      @lesson.prerequisite_ids.each do |p|
        Prerequisite.create(lesson_id: @lesson.id, prerequisite_lesson_id: p)
      end
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Lesson created..."
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

The other is this (from your logs):

> "lesson"=>{"name"=>"Lesson 6", "high_tempo"=>"200",
>   "low_tempo"=>"100", "interval"=>"10", "advance_tempo"=>"140",
>   "prerequisite_ids"=>["", "3", "4"]}, "commit"=>"Save"} Unpermitted
>   parameter: prerequisite_ids'`

In your controller, you are permitting

```
def lesson_params
  params.require(:lesson).permit(
    :name,
    :high_tempo,
    :low_tempo,
    :interval,
    :advance_tempo,
    prerequisites_attributes: [
      :lesson_id,
      :prerequisite_lesson_id
    ]
  )
end
```

But note that your actual data is coming in as `"lesson" => {..., "prerequisite_ids"=>["", "3", "4"]}`

So you should instead permit like this:

```
def lesson_params
  params.require(:lesson).permit(
    :name,
    :high_tempo,
    :low_tempo,
    :interval,
    :advance_tempo,
    prerequisite_ids: []
  )
end
```

Additionally, it looks like your `prerequisite_ids` are including a value that is an empty string. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929230/why-is-the-first-element-always-blank-in-my-rails-multi-select-using-an-embedde), it looks like you may need to add `include_hidden: true` to your select tag, like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:prerequisite_ids, Lesson.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true, include_hidden: true}) %>
```

Comment: This is what I'm seeing in the log: 

'Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"THaOnTF4jPv6duqqyxRMP7IIfpEPS9MrFJ5Ib50WohwyvP8dd085P0UQeD47jW2a65tI3eNeHVU0IZwL6hYpWw==", "lesson"=>{"name"=>"Lesson 6", "high_tempo"=>"200", "low_tempo"=>"100", "interval"=>"10", "advance_tempo"=>"140", "prerequisite_ids"=>["", "3", "4"]}, "commit"=>"Save"}
Unpermitted parameter: prerequisite_ids'

Comment: I've updated my answer to address another problem, which I believe you are seeing.

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same "Unpermitted parameter" error unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like for an array parameter, you must permit it as such. I've just updated the last bit of my answer, could you give that a try?

Comment: 'Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bjCBqvh+babDcXymJigWsCuP9AVKsRo2ZbvkEXXXMtwQ+vAqvknYYnwX7jLWsTcVchzCSaak1EhFBDB1Ate5mw==", "lesson"=>{"name"=>"Testing", "high_tempo"=>"200", "low_tempo"=>"100", "interval"=>"10", "advance_tempo"=>"140", "prerequisite_ids"=>["", "3", "4"]}, "commit"=>"Save"}
  Prerequisite Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "prerequisites".* FROM "prerequisites" WHERE "prerequisites"."id" IN (3, 4)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Prerequisite(#69945275660660) expected, got NilClass(#5898200)):'

Comment: Trying to figure out what is causing it. The array is submitted with a "" item in it for some reason, and that seems like it could be causing the error.

Comment: Looks like you may need to add `:include_hidden => true` to your select tag. There is a post about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929230/why-is-the-first-element-always-blank-in-my-rails-multi-select-using-an-embedde I've updated my answer

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can always as this as your first line of your controller action: `lesson_params[:prerequisite_ids].select!(&:present?)`, which will remove the empty value from the array.